# how to set width relative to grandparent elements not direct parent elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width

i'm trying to set some elements' width with percentage relative to grandparent elements' width. like this.

```
<style>
.grand{width:1000px; overflow:hidden;}
.parent{width:2000px; position:relative}
.child1{float:left; width:50%; height:200px; background-color:blue;}
.child2{float:left; width:50%; height:200px; background-color:green;}
</style>


<div class="grand">
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

But i have no idea how to make this done, how can i make child elements refer directly to it's grandparent elements not direct parent elements?  ( in this case if i set child elements width 50% it has to be 500px, not 1000px. )

are there possible ways to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use CSS [custom properties](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/#defining-variables), [`var()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/#using-variables) and [`calc()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#funcdef-calc) functions

```css
.grand {
--main-width: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent {
  width: calc(var(--main-width) * 2);
  position: relative
}

.child1, .child2 {
  float: left;
  width: calc(var(--main-width) / 2);
  height: 200px;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JamesDavidDeann To verify the expected values are set you can execute `document.querySelectorAll(".grand, .parent, .child1, .child2")
.forEach(el => console.log(\`${el.className}, width:${window.getComputedStyle(el).width}\`))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use absolute position to child element.

Apply this css:

```
.grand{width:1000px; overflow:hidden; position:relative;height:200px;}
.parent{width:2000px; }
.child1{float:left; width:50%; height:200px; background-color:blue; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}
.child2{float:left; width:50%; height:200px; background-color:green; position:absolute; top:0; left:50%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change it to:

> .parent{width:2000px; position:relative} --> .parent{width:1000%;
>   position:relative; display: inline;}

Answer (score 0):

```
#grand {width: 1000px; height:200px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;}
#parent {min-width: 100%; height: 100%; display: flex;}
.child {flex: 1; height: 100%;}
```

```
<script>
  var childCount = 4;
  var childSize = 50; // in percentage
  document.getElementById("parent").style.width = (childSize * childCount) + "%";
</script>
<div id="grand">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```